# How to add animations to a 3rd party library component

Tags: angular

I'm using [Primeng's Dialog](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dialog) component and I wanted to add an animation to increase its scale when it opens.

Adding a trigger animation to my component works and the CSS style changes in the DOM but the dialog does not change. I'm assuming it's because `p-dialog` is just the selector, how can I apply it for the `div` under it?

```
trigger('expandBox', [
  state('inactive', style({
    transform: 'scale(1)',
  })),
  state('active',   style({
    transform: 'scale(2)',
  })),
  transition('inactive => active', animate('100ms ease-in')),
  transition('active => inactive', animate('100ms ease-out'))
])

<p-dialog
  [@expandBox]='dialogVisibleString'
  header="Meeting Details - {{tileday}}" 
  ...
</p-dialog>
```

I have had this issue in the pass where I wanted to add animations to a 3rd party component and I've never been sure how to fix it.

Comment: as far as I know, you cant. But you can, however, get an element reference to content and container. Take a look at the dialog.ts source code: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/components/dialog/dialog.ts.